# UILabels and other elements added in IB are misplaced when running app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I load InfoViewController's view as a subview in `MainViewController` like this (declared in .h):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
mainInfoView = (MainInfoView *)[mainInfoViewController view];
 }
```

(MainViewController is push-presented from a segue from a tableviewcontroller cell and has a navigation bar.)

This is in `InfoViewController`'s viewDidLoad to set the size of view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(130, 0, 178, 299);
}
```

In the Size inspector for InfoViewController I've set the same size (with: 178, height: 299).
I disabled "Use Autolayout" both for InfoViewController in XIB and for the MainViewController in Storyboard.

I have some UILabels, UITextViews and UIImageViews in the `InfoViewController`. They are declared with properties in .h and synthesized in .m. and connected to the elements in the XIB. Their content is defined in viewWillAppear of `MainViewController` like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
 infoViewController.kategoriLabel.text = [[objArr objectAtIndex:detailIndex] objectForKey:@"Type"];
 }
```

When I run the app and this view is entered, some of the labels, images and textViews are suddenly placed in what appears to be random locations. This is only happening to some of the elements.

I have done this same thing in another app and it works fine on both simulator (iPhone 4 ver 6,0) and iPhone 5 device, but in this app it just gets messy on both.
I cannot seem to find anything different anywhere in the Utilities or anywhere else when I compare the apps.

If you have experienced something similar and solved it or if you might know what could be causing it, I will appreciate your answer. Thanks.

PS. I'm using Xcode 4.5.1

Comment: Can you make a simple project and upload it so we can take a look at view hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a different problem, but my brute-force resolution might work for you as well. In my case, I wanted to disable the nav bar on the final item in a series of view controllers. IB, though, won't let you remove the Nav bar so I had to do it manually in viewWillAppear. However, once the bar was hidden, IOS shifted up all my buttons and objects that had been defined in IB by the height of the (now hidden) nav bar.

I resorted to the following in the Controller's viewWillAppear. (objects tended to shift visibly when I tried this in viewWillAppear)

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //turn off nav bar
    [[self navigationController]setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    //correct positions of items that shift when the bar disappears
    myThing.center = CGPointMake(desired_x_coord, desired_y_coord);
    myOtherThing.center = CGPointMake(desired_x_coord2, desired_y_coord2);
    ...etc...

    //don't forget to call the base class
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Annoying, but worked. If you can't find the source of your objects moving, you could try forcing their positions using viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it later. Think its gonna do the thing but u think it gonna work without hiding the Nav bar? I kind of need it.

Comment: I looks like it was the navigation controller (bar) causing the trouble and I solved it by moving the properties for the affected object to the `MainInfoView.h` instead of `InfoViewController.h` but forcing their positions worked as well.